# Responsive Homepage (Tablet): one single column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

i'm working on this website http://tosamaganga.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/index.html
Is made with Bootstrap. Is fully responsive but i've some issues into the Homepage.

The 3 pictures, when you check the website on Ipad, does not looks "responsive". What i'm trying to do is to create a single orizzontal column on Ipad, with the 3 pictures inline.

How can i fix it?

```
 <!-- CONTENT -->
<section id="services" class="section text-center">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="section-title wow fadeIn"> </h2>
        <div class="row_2">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="single-service text-left wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay=".3s">
                    <div class="service-title">
                    </div>
                    <div class="service-content">
                        <img src="img/1_Kreis.jpg" widht="340" height="340" class="img-responsive" align="left" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

           <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="single-service text-left wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay=".3s">
                    <div class="service-title">
                    </div>
                    <div class="service-content">
                        <img src="img/ilona_home.jpg" widht="340" height="340" class="img-responsive" align="center" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="single-service text-left wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay=".3s">
                    <div class="service-title">
                    </div>
                    <div class="service-content">
                        <img src="img/tower_home.jpg" widht="340" height="340" class="img-responsive" align="right" />
             </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <br>
                <h3 align="left">Helfen, wo Hilfe lebensnotwendig ist.<br>Jeder Franken erreicht seine Bestimmung.</h3><br>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8"> 
                    <h4 align="left">Freunde von Tosamaganga</h4>
                    <p class="home_text" align="left">Die Stiftung „Freunde von Tosamaganga“ wird getragen von einer Gruppe von Unternehmern, Ärzten, Ingenieuren und medizinischem Fachpersonal, die sich zum Ziel gesetzt haben, etwas von dem zurück zu geben und zu fördern, was wir glücklicherweise als selbstverständlich ansehen.<br><br>So heterogen wie die Zusammensetzung unseres Teams ist, so vielfältig ist unser Engagement. Tansania ist eines der ärmsten Länder dieser Erde. Insbesondere im Landesinneren herrscht grosse Armut. Es fehlt an vielen lebensnotwendigen Dingen, wie sauberem Wasser, Strom und medizinischer Basisversorgung. Genau hier ist unser Ansatz.<br>Im Namen des Stiftungsrates danken wir Ihnen herzlich für Ihre Unterstützung.<br><br>
                        Prof. Dr. med. Robert E. Oellinger<br>Facharzt für plastische und ästhetische Chirurgie
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4"> 
                    <img src="img/oellinger.jpg" width="230" height="320" class="img-responsive" align="right">
               </div>

    </div>
    <!--/.container -->
</section>
<!-- END CONTENT -->
```

Comment: First thing to do is probably stick all of your columns into row divs. I don't think you're using the 12 columns correctly

Comment: Also you're spelling "width" wrong in the 3 images up top. You've spelled them "widht"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you are missing col-sm.
If you want to have the 3 images in line, in the 3 divs add the class col-sm-4 or replace col-md with col-sm.
If you want each picture to take full screen width use col-sm-12.

Answer (score 1):

Use a different column size `(col-sm-4)` and use the default `row` to hold those 12 columns in (generally). I would avoid using `align="left/center/right"`, you shouldn't need it, the grid should handle it and if you're using img-responsive then don't use fixed dimensions for the image inline (also width is spelled incorrectly > `widht="340"` should be `width="340"`).

Then you can use media queries to adjust your layout accordingly. See example.

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .service-content img {
    width: 340px;
    margin: 5px auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section id="services" class="section text-center">
    <div class="container">
         <h2 class="section-title wow fadeIn"> </h2>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="single-service text-left wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay=".3s">
                    <div class="service-title"></div>
                    <div class="service-content">
                        <img src="http://tosamaganga.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/img/1_Kreis.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="single-service text-left wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay=".3s">
                    <div class="service-title"></div>
                    <div class="service-content">
                        <img src="http://tosamaganga.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/img/1_Kreis.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="single-service text-left wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay=".3s">
                    <div class="service-title"></div>
                    <div class="service-content">
                        <img src="http://tosamaganga.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/img/1_Kreis.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <br>
                 <h3 align="left">Helfen, wo Hilfe lebensnotwendig ist.<br>Jeder Franken erreicht seine Bestimmung.</h3>

                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                 <h4 align="left">Freunde von Tosamaganga</h4>

                <p class="home_text" align="left">Die Stiftung „Freunde von Tosamaganga“ wird getragen von einer Gruppe von Unternehmern, Ärzten, Ingenieuren und medizinischem Fachpersonal, die sich zum Ziel gesetzt haben, etwas von dem zurück zu geben und zu fördern, was wir glücklicherweise als selbstverständlich ansehen.
                    <br>
                    <br>So heterogen wie die Zusammensetzung unseres Teams ist, so vielfältig ist unser Engagement. Tansania ist eines der ärmsten Länder dieser Erde. Insbesondere im Landesinneren herrscht grosse Armut. Es fehlt an vielen lebensnotwendigen Dingen, wie sauberem Wasser, Strom und medizinischer Basisversorgung. Genau hier ist unser Ansatz.
                    <br>Im Namen des Stiftungsrates danken wir Ihnen herzlich für Ihre Unterstützung.
                    <br>
                    <br>Prof. Dr. med. Robert E. Oellinger
                    <br>Facharzt für plastische und ästhetische Chirurgie</div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="service-content">
                <img src="http://tosamaganga.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/img/oellinger.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            </div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- END CONTENT -->
<!-- FOOTER CONTENT -->
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="text-muted">© 2015 - Freunde für Tosamaganga. All rights reserved.</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a grid issue.
What grid containers are you using for the images?

I'm guessing it's like the first one on this page:
[BootstrapGrid](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

Just to add, `.col-md-4` should do the trick.

Comment: For the pictures i'm using col-md-4 yes

I've edited the first post

Comment: It seems to be working ok for me now. The width seems to be misspelled too.